# Is it possible to replace OS on a node in a kubernetes cluster without downtime

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have a three-node Kubernetes cluster running in my home lab, where two nodes are currently running Debian, and the third is running Ubuntu.

> ```
> $ kubectl get nodes
> NAME         STATUS                        ROLES                         AGE    VERSION
> k8s-worker2  NotReady,SchedulingDisabled   worker                        265d   v1.25.4+k3s1
> k8s-master   Ready                         control-plane,master,worker   266d   v1.25.4+k3s1
> k8s-worker1  Ready                         worker                        266d   v1.25.4+k3s1
> ```

I want to replace my Ubuntu OS with Debian on my master node.

### My plan:

1. Backup all the configuration and keys on *k8s-master* (/home, /usr, /etc, /var)
2. Set up my *k8s-worker1* as `control-plane` and `master`
3. Mark *k8s-master* as `SchedulingDisabled`
4. Turn off *k8s-master*
5. Verify that my applications still work
6. Reformat and install Debian on the *k8s-master*
7. Reinstall K3S and copy config from backup to *k8s-master*
8. Remove *k8s-worker1* as `master`

### My Concerns:

I am not sure if there is a step I am missing. I am worried if my routes will work (I have no load balancers set up so the ports are currently exposed on the master node..., So I assume that I'd have to do some further configuration before this would work)